# Semi-transparent materials are looking fine under viewport render, but are invisible under normal render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Semi-transparent materials are looking fine under viewport render, but are invisible under normal render.

Here are my material nodes:

[image]

Here is a difference between viewport render and normal render:

[image]

Comment: Are the objects enabled for rendering (the camera icon on the ouliner)?

Comment: You are genius. I probably used some random shortcut and didn't noticed that.